# Primefaces PostConstruct And User name

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem in integrating Spring Security and JSF. I'm trying to access to Username in a `@PostConstruct` method but I get `NullPointerException`.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
     Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      //auth is null
     String userName = auth.getName(); 

}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: @Beka92 You didn't specify what your bean is about and why you think the username should be available when it gets constructed.